# How does one pass parameters to a function in Swift? Missing argument in call

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Swift function parameters not accepted. Missing argument?

```
Calculate(theA, theB) //error: Missing argument label 'sideB:' in call

func Calculate(sideA: Int, sideB: Int) -> Int {
    var ans = sideA + sideB
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `sideB:` in your function call. I didn't want to rewrite your code (since you posted an image) but here's the working function call.

```
func calcButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let a: Int = 10
    let b: Int = 11

    calculate(a, sideB: b) //<-- Missing it here
}

func calculate(sideA: Int, sideB: Int) -> Int {
    let a = sideA + sideB
    return a
}
```

you might also want to have both variables in the function call so you can do this instead:

```
func calcButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let a: Int = 10
    let b: Int = 11

    calculate(sideA: a, sideB: b)
}

func calculate(sideA A: Int, sideB B: Int) -> Int {
    return A + B
}
```

---

Just an FYI, use tab completion instead of writing out the function. Xcode will let you know all the function variables with placeholders so you can type them in.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the sideB param name in swift 3 first parameter is optional but second param is Mandatory that _ in there That’s an underscore. It changes the way the method is called. To illustrate this, here’s a very simple function:

```
func doStuff(thing: String) {
    // do stuff with "thing"
}
```

It’s empty, because its contents don’t matter. Instead, let’s focus on how it’s called. Right now, it’s called like this:

```
doStuff(thing: "Hello")
```

You need to write the name of the thing parameter when you call the doStuff() function. This is a feature of Swift, and helps make your code easier to read. Sometimes, though, it doesn’t really make sense to have a name for the first parameter, usually because it’s built into the method name.

When that happens, you use the underscore character like this:

```
func doStuff(_ thing: String) {
    // do stuff with "thing"
}
```

That means “when I call this function I don’t want to write thing, but inside the function I want to use thing to refer to the value that was passed in.